# new to WordPress can someone point me to right direction

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to build a website on WordPress and I am struggling to make transitions like in the following website
https://www.zerodesigns.in

From left to right when take cursor to each words
Can someone point me to the right directions
Tya

Answer (score -1):

So this question is a little vague, in the future you will get better answers if you provide specifics in what you are looking for, but it won't hurt anyone to answer this as is. The website you provided was built in Elementor, so I would suggest looking at their [Site](https://elementor.com/) if you are looking for exactly what they have.

Some other effects I noticed that you can look into that are not necessary specific to Elementor. They are using parallax (both in the basic `background-attachment: fixed;` meaning of the word, as well as the more modern interpretation becoming more popular). [Here](https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic) is an example of a library that includes some scroll based animations seen in your example. One last effect that can be replicated outside of Elementor is an advanced slider. There are several good plugins that do this [SliderRevolution](https://www.sliderrevolution.com/) is one that I have used.

Hopefully this has helped some. Animations on Websites is a very big field, and can be a bit daunting to get into. I will try to answer questions when if I can.